# Getting rows where columns have certain values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am relatively new to python and am trying to get rows where columns have certain values.

Here is example of my code

```
item=mydf[mydf["Item Name"]=="Pregabalin"]
type=mydf[mydf["type"]=="Pregabalin 300mg"]
mydf[item & Strength]
```

However when I run this I get an error 
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and what I can do just to return specific values?
Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use "bitwise and" for masks like as follows:

```
item = mydf["Item Name"]=="Pregabalin"
typ = mydf["type"]=="Pregabalin 300mg"

mydf[item & typ]
```

or simply (in the following case we must use parentheses because of [Operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)):

```
mydf[(mydf["Item Name"]=="Pregabalin") & (mydf["type"]=="Pregabalin 300mg")]
```

Comment: Slow day today...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you! this works great... 
I have another question for you how can I do this with numeric data;

    mydf[(mydf["Item Name"]=="Pregabalin") & (mydf["Quantity"]=="2.0")]

I am receiving this error
   TypeError: invalid type comparison when I use the above code

Comment: @Katie Quantity may be a float. Try `mydf['Quantity'] == 2.0`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you so much!!